# Subversion: How to find the differences between two tags?

Tags: svn, diff

I know that a  diff between two tags lists the 'files' which have been changed between those two tags by the following method.

```
svn diff tag1 tag2 |grep Index:
```

Is there any property in Subversion or some technique to find out revision numbers which caused those files to change (i.e differences between tag1 version of the file and tag2 version of the same file)?

Thx 
Vandana

Answer (score 14):

You can first find the revisions of the tags:

```
svn info http://svn.twig-project.org/tags/RELEASE_0_9_7 | grep 'Last Changed Rev'
Last Changed Rev: 331

svn info http://svn.twig-project.org/tags/RELEASE_0_9_8 | grep 'Last Changed Rev'
Last Changed Rev: 343
```

You're not really looking for a diff, you are looking for a log. So do a verbose log between those revisions and you will get the commits including changed files.

```
svn log -v -q -r 331:343 http://svn.twig-project.org/trunk

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r332 | fabien | 2010-06-12 18:30:02 +0200 (Sat, 12 Jun 2010)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/CHANGELOG
   M /trunk/lib/Twig/Environment.php
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r333 | fabien | 2010-06-12 18:45:04 +0200 (Sat, 12 Jun 2010)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/CHANGELOG
   M /trunk/lib/Twig/Environment.php
```

Comment: There is an issue with this version : if you copy trunk from r331 that creates (for example) r367, you will have the changelog from r367, not r331 as expected

Comment: This assumes a linear history without branches.

Comment: This won't work with tags created retrospectively from particular revisions, as Last Changed Rev is the revision number created when the tag was made.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list of revisions that could be merged from one tag to another, you can generate it with the following:

```
    svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible URL_TAG_1 URL_TAG_2
```

Answer (score 3):

Since SVN [version 1.9](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/CHANGES) you have `--log` option for `svn mergeinfo`:

```
svn mergeinfo --log --show-revs eligible SOURCE TARGET
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which files have been changed between two tags use in a working copy:

```
svn merge --dry-run URL_TAG_1 URL_TAG_2
```

Answer (score 2):

The following shell script takes a SOURCE and a DEST, and shows changesets in SOURCE that has not been merged into DEST.

So, to answer the original question:

```
svnincoming ^/tags/TAG1 ^/tags/TAG2
```

Or to see changes in trunk that hasn't been merged into the working copy branch:

```
cd /working/copy/
svnincoming ^/trunk
```

The `svnincoming` script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e

SOURCE="$1"
DEST="${2:-.}"

if [ "$SOURCE" = "" ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` SOURCE[@REV] [DEST[@REV]]"
    echo "List revisions eligible for merging from SOURCE to DEST (or '.', if omitted)."
    exit 1
fi

svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible "$SOURCE" "$DEST" | sed 's/^/-/' | xargs -d '\n' svn log "$SOURCE"
```

Comment: fyi - I try this script and get "svn: E155010: The node '/path/to/working/copy/^tags/V2.2.821' was not found."

Comment: @Hippyjim: Be sure to type `^/tags`, not just `^tags`. Or maybe you're using an old Subversion client? (The caret notation requires 1.6 or later.) You can also try replacing the caret with your "Repository Root" URL (as shown by `svn info`), which is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

with svn version 1.9.7, although my tags are not in the same branch, it works !

```
svn diff --old=URL_TAG_1 --new=URL_TAG_2
```