# SVN diff in two project versions

Tags: svn, diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subversion: How to find the differences between two tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270322/subversion-how-to-find-the-differences-between-two-tags)

I'm working on a multi-module project. I need to get a diff between subversion (svn) tags (which represent releases). To be more specific, I want to find out which modules have changed from one release to the other. Could you please advise on that?

Comment: @nvartolomei - only parttially duplicate and top-voted answer is **not best**

Answer (score 1):

I'll use example from linked by @nvartolome question (this answer), but - with different commands-set and even **results**

- *If* your **modules are dirs**, you want to know only **which modules have changed** and agree to do **hand-work by eyes**: will do 2 ls

Older tag

```
z:\>svn ls -v http://svn.twig-project.org/tags/RELEASE_0_9_7
    331 fabien                июн 12  2010 ./
      4 fabien            191 окт 08  2009 AUTHORS
    326 fabien           7950 июн 12  2010 CHANGELOG
      4 fabien           1522 окт 08  2009 LICENSE
      4 fabien            341 окт 08  2009 README.markdown
    278 fabien                май 11  2010 bin/
    326 fabien                июн 12  2010 doc/
    328 fabien                июн 12  2010 lib/
     23 fabien           1854 окт 12  2009 package.xml.tpl
    309 fabien            652 июн 08  2010 phpunit.xml
    325 fabien                июн 12  2010 test/
```

Newer tag

```
z:\>svn ls -v http://svn.twig-project.org/tags/RELEASE_0_9_8
    343 fabien                июн 29  2010 ./
      4 fabien            191 окт 08  2009 AUTHORS
    342 fabien           8566 июн 29  2010 CHANGELOG
      4 fabien           1522 окт 08  2009 LICENSE
      4 fabien            341 окт 08  2009 README.markdown
    278 fabien                май 11  2010 bin/
    341 fabien                июн 28  2010 doc/
    342 fabien                июн 29  2010 lib/
     23 fabien           1854 окт 12  2009 package.xml.tpl
    309 fabien            652 июн 08  2010 phpunit.xml
    341 fabien                июн 28  2010 test/
```

First column is last revision of commit - just find (diff or eyes) changed revisions in dirs

- If you want do it even at file-level in a more automatic way: `z:\>svn diff --summarize http://svn.twig-project.org/tags/RELEASE_0_9_7 http://svn.twig-project.org/tags/RELEASE_0_9_8`

Result will be like

```
D       http://svn.twig-project.org/tags/RELEASE_0_9_7/test/fixtures/expressions/binary.test
...

A       http://svn.twig-project.org/tags/RELEASE_0_9_7/test/Twig/Tests/TemplateTest.php
M       http://svn.twig-project.org/tags/RELEASE_0_9_7/test/Twig/Tests/Node/DebugTest.php
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. My modules are indeed directories, so I'll probably use the "svn ls -v".